# How to programmatically log-in to Active-Directory without additional setting on AD?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, authentication, active-directory, powerbi-embedded

I need to log-in to Azure Active Directory to display the embedded report on a website using asp.net MVC.

However, the API provided is only valid for only username and password.

For logging-on to the AD, all I need to do is to type-in username (email address) and the log-in portal will redirect me to another log-in page and then type in and username and password.

I wonder is there anyway to do the programmatically log-in without using the application secret?

Comment: What do you mean with `However, the API provided is only valid for only username and password.`?

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to implement Power BI report embedding using Azure AD authentication:

1. User Owns Data embedding
2. App Owns Data embedding

If you don't want user sign-in experience, you can implement App Owns Data authentication in the following ways:

1. Client secret
2. Master user credentials (username and password (MFA disabled account))

Please go through [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embedded/embed-sample-for-customers) to achieve your goal and also, [here](https://github.com/microsoft/PowerBI-Developer-Samples) is a sample code for it.